# Consecutive conditional Future calls (in Play Scala server) not working

Tags: scala, playframework, async-await, future

I am using the below code to fetch news from a remote site in my Play Scala application server (2.5.x). I am using the suggested mechanism from "https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS".
The use case is in 2 steps:

1. Call remote API-2 to fetch the news content using a cached token.
2. If the token is invalid/expired, call remote API-1 to get a token and cache it.

Problem: I am not able to avoid step #2 even if the cached token is valid. Therefore I am fetching the token for each call of this `Action` in `listRemoteNews`.

If I use `if-else` conditions, then I get compile errors as below. Note that I have tried for comprehensions, too, but I need to still use `if` conditions there. Then I get the same compile errors.

```
[error] /sandbox/git/play-scala-app.repo/app/controllers/remoteapi/ListRemoteNewsController.scala:26: overloaded method value async with alternatives:
[error]   [A](bodyParser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[A])(block: play.api.mvc.Request[A] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[A] <and>
[error]   (block: play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   (block: => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
[error]  cannot be applied to (scala.concurrent.Future[Any])
[error]    def listRemoteNews = Action.async {
```

Code section below (`requestOne` and `requestTwo` are methods forming `WSRequest` and returning `Future[WSResponse]`):

```
@Singleton
class ListRemoteNewsController @Inject()(ws: WSClient)(implicit context: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {
   def listRemoteNews = Action.async {
      println("<--- Stored Token 1: " + remoteToken)
      val responseTwo: Future[WSResponse] = requestTwo.withQueryString("token" -> remoteToken).get()
      val resp: Future[JsValue] = responseTwo.map {
         response =>
               response.json
      }
      resp.map {
         response => {
            Ok(response)
         }
      }

      println("<-- Get token...")
      val responseOne: Future[WSResponse] = requestOne
      val resp2: Future[String] = responseOne.map {
         response => {
            remoteToken = (response.json  \ "token_list" \ "token").as[String]
            println("<--- Obtained token 2: " + remoteToken)
            remoteToken
         }
      }

      val responseThree: Future[WSResponse] = requestTwo.withQueryString("token" -> remoteToken).get()
      responseThree.map {
         response => {
            println("<--- status: " + response.status)
            Ok(response.json)
         }

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Futures are things that must be composed. Right now, you're making a number of different requests, which each return futures, but you're not returning those futures or combining them together in any way. Mapping a future is pointless if you don't do anything with the new future returned by the map function.

What you need to do is compose your futures, and this is done using methods like `flatMap`.

So here's roughly what I'm guessing your code should look like:

```
requestTwo.withQueryString("token" -> remoteToken).get().flatMap { response =>
  if (tokenWasValid(response)) {
    Future.successful(Ok(response.json))
  } else {
    requestOne.get().flatMap { tokenResponse =>
      val remoteToken = (response.json  \ "token_list" \ "token").as[String]
      requestTwo.withQueryString("token" -> remoteToken).get()
    }.map { response =>
      Ok(response.json)
    }
  }
}
```

If the above makes no sense whatsoever, then I recommend you stop and read up on Scala futures before doing anything else.

Here's a selection of tutorials I found by doing a quick Google search:

http://code.hootsuite.com/introduction-to-futures-in-scala/
https://danielasfregola.com/2015/04/01/how-to-compose-scala-futures/
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html

Comment: That was a cool solution. Thanks a lot. Initially it looked very cryptic to me. But after spending time learning through the links you posted above, it seems so elegant. Futures are simply great !
BTW, I made a minor twist to the solution as below. Do you any issues with it ?

`requestTwo.withQueryString("token" -> remoteToken).get().map {
                                               response => Ok(response.json)
                                               }
`